# hgignore for eclipse projects

Tags: eclipse, version-control, mercurial

I'd like to share an eclipse project with several people via version control (in my case mercurial). Can you tell me which files I should add to the hgignore-file?

What about the `.settings` folder, `.classpath` and `.project` files? Any other things to be aware of? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add only those three files/directories : .settings, .classpath and .project

Also, you need to include into hgignore-file the directory where .class files are generated.

Comment: are you sure about the project file? eclipse.org says: "When a project is created in the workspace, a project description file is automatically generated that describes the project.  The purpose of this file is to make the project self-describing, so that a project that is zipped up or released to a server can be correctly recreated in another workspace. "

Comment: With .project you can recreate the project, but you need also the dependencies. With .classpath you have the list of dependencies, but all users need to have the dependencies in the same directory. .project helps you to recreate de project in eclipse, but it´s not enough.

Comment: .project holds any project-specific settings (like which execution environment is required). Once the .project file has been created, other users can import the existing project with all dependencies into their workspace.